# Firebase / Google Cloud Function cron function returns INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a scheduled Cloud Function as in [this article](https://codeburst.io/cron-cloud-functions-for-firebase-724728b1683a).

I've got two functions in my `/functions/index.js`.  The first one is a https function and it works correctly, but `englishSyntax` doesn't run.

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.englishSyntax = functions.pubsub
    .schedule('every 30 seconds')
    .timeZone('America/New_York')
  .onRun(context => {
    console.log('triggered every 30 secs', context);
});
```

I'm on the minimum versions for cron.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

In my Logs Viewer:

```
2019-08-23 11:18:52.048 EDT
Cloud Scheduler API
CreateJob
us-central1
email@mail.com
INVALID_ARGUMENT
```

And the details:

```
  status: {
   code:  3    
   message:  "INVALID_ARGUMENT"    
  }
...
resource: {
  labels: {
   method:  ""    
   project_id:  "my-project"    
   service:  ""    
  }
  type:  "audited_resource"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"
```

What does this error indicate? How can I fix it so that it runs my function on schedule?  Besides the status of the function, where would I check the `console.log` output to verify it's working?

Comment: Did you tried with other cron expressions? Like hour or so?

Comment: I've tried `every 60 seconds` and `every minute`.  I'm using the small timeframe so I can test if it's even working.  All of them give me the same result.

Comment: If you're getting errors that don't explain what is going wrong, contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thank you guys both.  You helped me look in the right place.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The error message was accurate after all.  The problem is that `seconds` is not a valid argument.  It needed to be either `minutes` or `hours`.  It seems that `every minute` still needs a numerical second arg as well.  The docs make it more clear exactly how "English-y" the syntax really is or isn't.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#start-time